# Set build number of downstream jobs from master job in Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I have 2 Jenkins slaves with 1 master (3 machines). For example Slave1 and Slave2. I have two jobs and used labels to bind the jobs to the slaves. For example Job1 is bound to Slave1 and Job2 is bound to Slave2. Both are free style jobs. I created a free style job which only invokes Job1 and Job2 so they run on the slaves at the same time. I'd like for the two jobs to always build with the same build number or inherit the build number from the upstream job. Is there a way I could send the build number from the main job to the the two downstream jobs? I'd like to prevent Job1 and Job2's build numbers from getting out of sync which would happen if one is run by itself.

Comment: Why not just prevent one job from running by itself? Inheriting a build number from an upstream job would only result in more pain if you still allow individual runs of downstream builders, because you'll wind up with an upstream build number that duplicates an earlier individual run.

Comment: @Amber Do I use this? `Disable Build (No new builds will be executed until the project is re-enabled.)` ? ... That's the only setting I see that might do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/): [Job::updateNextBuildNumber(int)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html#updateNextBuildNumber%28int%29). So you can try the following: from a system Groovy script (that can be run via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)) locate the child job objects, set the build number on them via the method above; then trigger them.

You'll still may get problems, however. For example, if one of those jobs is triggered manually you may not be able to set a number on it (build numbers have to increase).